# Dúvida com passagem de Parâmetro asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Está chamando o controller mais não esta chamando a ActionResult (Resolvido)
Tenho a minha view:

```html
@model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_MENU>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.Partial("_navbarInterno")

@Html.Partial("_PartialLogin")




<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
        Seleccione una opción
    </a>

    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <a href="/Operacao/Index/@item.idmenu" class="list-group-item">@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.descricaomenu)</a>
        }
    }

</div>
```

no controller:

```html
        // GET: Operacao
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            //pega a opção selecionada para trazer as opções
            int opcao = id;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Coloca o nome da view e a pasta onde ela está, por favor?

Comment: <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Operacao", @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.idmenu))" class="list-group-item">@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.descricaomenu)</a>

Comment: @Ricardo esta na pergunta,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem alguns erros muito sério nesse código.

Primeiro, você está esperando um `Model` em sua `ActionResult`, porém não está passando um `Model` para ela.

Segundo, você está usando `[HttpPost]` e está querendo passar via `GET` com o `@Url.Action`.

Terceiro, se quiser passar o `idMenu` como parâmetro, não utilize o `@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.idmenu)`, utilize apenas o `item.idmenu`.

Agora vamos a solução.

Se você quer passar um model, ou você faz isso por `ajax` ou manda por post (via `form`). Porém, em seu código me parece que está querendo passar apenas o `idMenu`. Se for isso, basta alterar seu `controller` e seu `@Url.Action` para receber e passar o `idMenu`, respectivamente. Ficaria assim:

```
  //Retire o [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int idMenu)//O nome aqui é apenas para estudos, pode ser o que quiser.
    {
        int CodigoOpcao = model.idmenu;



       //aqui eu verifico se chamo a modalidade ou outra opção
       //preciso 
        return View();
    }
```

E em seu `@Url.Action`, coloque desta forma:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Operacao", new{idMenu = item.idmenu})" class="list-group-item">@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.descricaomenu)</a>
```

Comment: Deu tudo certo, eu fiz a alteração do código postado

Comment: @itasouza não esqueça de aceitar a resposta se ela lhe ajudou a resolver o seu problema

Comment: @RichardDias, sim, com certeza, agradeço o lembrete!